# Unable to install the required packages for developing Maynard desktop

Tags: software-installation, maynard

I am attempting to install the new Maynard desktop, just to give it a try. I added the

```
# Source packages for Maynard.
deb-src http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy wayland
```

lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/collabora-experimental.list` and then ran `sudo apt-get update` as mentioned on the [wiki page](https://github.com/raspberrypi/maynard/wiki/Develop-on-a-Raspberry-Pi) for developing Maynard on the Pi. I know the source packages lines are correct, as they showed up when I ran `apt-get update`.

However, when I got to the

> 3 Install the development packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install git
> sudo apt-get build-dep maynard
> ```

part, it just tells me `Unable to locate package build-dep Unable to locate package maynard`.

Does anyone have any clue why this is? I've run `rpi-update` and I'm running `apt-get upgrade` now, but I have no clue why it won't download those two packages.

Comment: I just download the script then ran `wget http://raspberrypi.collabora.co.uk/setup-maynard.sh` I suggest you backup your Pi first. maynard didn't do much and it broke my normal GUI

Comment: @Milliways I ended up doing that, now I'm leaving this question up to see if I can get answers regarding why the software isn't being recognized as installable.